# How do I enable scripts when setting document using WebBrowser.DocumentText

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using the Windows Forms WebBrowser control, and getting it to display a document that I create on the fly and set using the DocumentText property. The document that I create references a script file in the same directory as my executable. Trouble is, when the WebBrowser control displays the page, the scripts aren't enabled.

Now I know that IE7 introduced a new security feature that impacted on this scenario. I remember having to do something about setting a FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT key somewhere in the registry under the IE Key, but I can't figure out exactly where. Does anybody have instructions for this.

Even better, is there a way of enabling my Scenario without changing the registry? I don't really want to have to supply an installer with my executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You will need to mark your "page". Just after the **html** tag, put in:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0020)http://www.test.com/ -->
```

0020 is the length of the following url (including /)

This make sure the page you are viewing will be run in the internet security zone, thus, unless set otherwise, have script enabled.